# how to connect oracle server with emacs?

Tags: sql, oracle, emacs

I want to connect to the server with Emacs. I found this link : 
[EmacsWiki:sqlPlus](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/SqlPlus)

I did what was described there and added the following lines to my .emacs file:

> (require 'tabbar) 
>   (require 'ide-skel) 
>   (require 'sqlplus)

When I try to `M-x - "sql-oracle"` it asks me to enter `"User: "`, `"Password: "`, and `"Database: "`, but I don't know `"database"`, all I have is this data:

> IP (Host Name):  #######  
>   Port: #### 
>   SID: orcl 
>   UserName: ####  
>   Password: ####

How can I make emacs ask me to fill only (and all of) this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect to the Oracle using `M-x sqlplus`. Then you give a connection string like `user/password@SID`

If it doesn't work then try to connect to Oracle using sqlplus from the command prompt.

And check the file [Tnsnames.ora](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora).